# tab completion stops working in IPython with vi-insert set in .inputrc

Tags: ipython, readline

I opened an issue for this [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6271), but it's not strictly an IPython issue apparently. Wondering if anyone has any intuition about what's going on.

When I have `set keymap vi-insert` in my .inputrc, tab completion and history completion stops working in IPython after I make certain keystrokes in edit mode. For example, if while typing I type an `e` or an `r` not as the first letter of a line and then hit up to complete the command using my history, tab completion stops working and hitting tab gives a hard tab. I'm also not able to search the history using partial matches. E.g., typing `import<UP>` just scrolls through my history sequentially rather than only giving commands that start with import.

Any ideas?